# Flutter: How can I use both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses with my client?

Tags: flutter, networking, udp, ipv6

I have a server where I need to connect. My client is written in Dart, and binds the socket like this:

```
static Future<RawDatagramSocket> rDgS =
      RawDatagramSocket.bind(InternetAddress.anyIPv4, 50943);
```

Can I use something else to not specify the version of the IP-protocol to make it connect on both IPv4 and IPv6-only networks? I am using UDP sockets.

I have tried both anyIPv4 and andIPv6 using both server IP-addresses (IPv4 and IPv6) since I don't have a DNS hostname for my server. Only anyIPv4 works with IPv4 address.

Comment: IPv4 and IPv6 are two completely separate and incompatible protocols. You connect to an IPv4 host with IPv4, and you connect to an IPv6 host with IPv6. Both IPs can run on the same interface and they are separate, but IPv4 cannot directly connect to IPv6, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accept IPv6 connections, you have to have a IPv6 address. Same for accepting IPv4. Similarly, to connect, you both have to be using the same protocol. IPv4 and IPv6 are not interchangeable.